# How to delete sheet from an existing excel file using JExel

Tags: java, jxl, jexcelapi

I am trying to delete sheet from an existing excel file. can any one suggest how to do that.

Comment: I would advise that you expand your question because you're not providing enough information for anyone to realistically help you. This usually leads to a protracted and frustrating round of requests in the comments for more information by other users who **really do want to help you**. For example, include in the question: code snippets/samples, the API you're using, stack traces, screen shots etc. When you've done this, flag to have your question re-opened. Please also take the time to [read this](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you're trying to achieve.

Brute force method: the never Excel file format (*.XLSX) is just a zipped folder with bunch of XML files inside. One of the file describes worksheets included in document. What you could do is to unzip it, change that file to include only worksheets you need and zip it back. Upon opening such modified file Excel would complain but other tools, such as Apache POI would work just fine and you could seriously reduce memory consumption on large documents by excluding worksheets you don't need.

Perhaps there is a more elegant way.